# is there any way to find out the form was opened by which button?

Tags: vb.net

i have a form (eg: frm1) with multiple buttons and each button is opening the form (eg:frm2).
here is the problem. can i find that the frm2 was opened by which button ? since all the buttons are opening the same form.

need Help!

Comment: Why is it important? If it is, create a property in `frm2` and assign a value to that property in the button-click event handler. There you know what was clicked.

Comment: Instead of the form trying to figure out which button opened it, the button should tell the form that it was the one that opened it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i did the same thing, but i m looking for better way

Comment: @Mib-af: in what way _better_? You have already the best way in terms of readability and maintainability. What don't you like?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i used the text property of target form in the button_click event so that i can find the form was opened by which button. its not efficient

Comment: @Mib-af: provide a custom property and don't use the `Form.Text` property. The duplicate shows an example.

Comment: @TimSchmelter can u provide a custom property ?

Comment: Of course you can, a form is just a class

Comment: @TimSchmelter please provide an example

Comment: `Public Property WhichButton As String`